# Losing session variables/cookies only in Chrome [pretty URL's & .htaccess]

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, google-chrome

this issue has been around and there's a few different versions of it but I'm stumped. First I'll let you know what my setup is...

CodeIgniter install
Works fine on all browsers except chrome...
I've narrowed the problem down to pretty URL's and .htaccess
sessions are stored in DB

Basically if I use codeigniter's default bootstrap structure index.php/controller it works fine but when I use a mod rewrite .htaccess the sessions get lost, only in chrome.

**Some of the things I saw out there, that i've tried...**

*favicon.ico in root* http://bit.ly/UFsYjj and [bit.ly/JPUzub](http://bit.ly/JPUzub)

*Switching to cookies and setting paths* [bit.ly/JPUzub](http://bit.ly/JPUzub)

for me it really boils down to the fact that the htaccess removal of index.php is causing the session issue. my codeigniter settings are as follows(note* if tried all different configurations of these settings like no domain etc.):

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 99999;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".mydomain.com";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

And my htaccess was as follows(now it's currently blank...):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php



</IfModule>
```

Comment: CI sores in the session cookie the session Id, user-agent and IP address. If one of them does not match, it will invalidate the session (and all the associated data). Do you have any extra request to the server that may invalidate your session? Check the Apache logs if possible

Comment: It's not that - look at the config, both `sess_match_ip` and `sess_match_useragent` are set to FALSE.

Comment: The htaccess posted starts by trying to prevent the favicon problem without you creating a favicon file - `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)` BUT it won't work because there's another copy of the rewrite rule at the end of the file which lacks that condition.  If you don't have a favicon.ico file, you need to try removing the last three Rewrite* lines in the htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your session expiration to zero.

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```